# How to avoid a spurious space when combining frame, centering and another environment?

Tags: beamer, spacing, environments

I want to create a special environment in `beamer`, which combines several environments, one of which is `center`. However, when using my newly created environment, I get an additional space in comparison to using the commands manually.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=myenv]\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{c}}
{\end{tabular}\end{center}\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}%
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%
\end{myenv}

\begin{frame}\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{c}%
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%
\end{tabular}\end{center}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the second frame, the text is centred as intended; in the first frame it is shifted to the left as if it contained an additional space at the end.

The same happens with some environments other than `tabular` but not if I do not nest another environment inside `center`. Using `\ignorespacesafterend` does not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the [Beamer manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) v3.33 at the end of page 62, when trying to use a `frame` environment inside `\newenvironment`, the ending must end with `\end{frame}` and not contain any other `\end` command, since the actual mechanics are somewhat sensitive. So in order to add additional environments, the manual suggests to define a separate new command to contain it all.

Here is a modified version based on your example.

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{\begin{frame}\startmyenv}
{\stopmyenv\end{frame}}

\newcommand\startmyenv{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{c}}
\newcommand\stopmyenv{\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{myenv}

\begin{frame}\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{c}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{tabular}\end{center}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output of the above example should render two identical frames without spurious spaces.

Answer (score 1):

As I just found out, using `fragile=singleslide` (instead of just `fragile`) as an argument of `frame` solves this particular issue too. However, [the accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197648/28608) is likely to fix other issues as well and arguably should be the preferred way to do it.